# Closing different workbook ends code execution of current workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run `foo` in `Book1.xlsm` that runs another sub, `bar`, in `Book2.xlsm`.  Following is the code for both:

In Book1:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim oldBook As Workbook: Set oldBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim newBook As Workbook: Set newBook = Workbooks("Book2.xlsm")

    Application.Run "'Book2.xlsm'!Module1.bar", oldBook
End Sub
```

In Book2:

```
Sub bar(book As Workbook)
    book.Close False
    Debug.Print "Closed Workbook!"
    MsgBox "Closed workbook!"
End Sub
```

The execution of `foo` runs perfectly fine and the control is passed onto `bar` in `Book2.xlsm`.  The line `book.Close false` runs perfectly fine (closes `Book1.xlsm`), but code execution stops immediately without any warning (no messages in console or popup).  Shouldn't both lines be executed in `Book2.xlsm` since the control was passed to `bar`?

I tried this by calling `bar workbooks(1)` (`workbooks(1) = Book1.xlsm`) and the entirety of the code runs perfectly fine, as expected.  Shouldn't the same happen

How do I preserve code execution in the first scenario, i.e. `foo` runs `bar`, change workbooks, close `Book1.xlsm` and continue execution of `bar`?

Comment: Because  foo() is the caller on the stack, and once it is closed, all its child processes are closed

Comment: That makes sense.  As for the second part of my question, how can I continue on with `bar` if the original workbook were closed first?

Comment: Why not close Book1 in Book 1 - after running the code in Book 2 and transferring control back to Book 2

Comment: Don't spaghettify logic like this. The code/workbook that's responsible for opening a resource (be it a workbook, a file, a database connection, *anything*) should be the code that's responsible for closing that resource / cleaning up.

Comment: If you need to run code and control things at *application level*, consider making an Excel add-in. That way you get an "overarching" component that is in a position to coordinate who gets to do what.

Answer (score 3):

Reconsider who's responsible for what. It's not normal that a workbook is just given any random `Workbook` object and proceeds to `Close` it.

Sure you can hack around the fact that you're essentially closing the owner of the call stack, but the root of the problem is, when you have `WorkbookA` responsible for doing something, and that something involves opening or creating `WorkbookB`, then it's `WorkbookA`'s responsibility to close `WorkbookB` when it's done.

`Book2` has no business closing anything. Assuming the real macro actually does something more than just closing it, then it should do its thing and then let the caller decide whether to close the workbook or leave it open; `Book2!Bar` is given a resource that it doesn't own: it's beyond its responsibility to close that resource.

Maybe this can serve as a simple illustration:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    Set t = New Thing
    UseTheThing t
    t.SomeMethod ' error 91: object reference is gone!
End Sub

Private Sub UseTheThing(ByRef t As Thing)
    t.Foobar 42
    Set t = Nothing ' not your job!
End Sub
```

Working around the natural order of things (caller -> callee -> back to caller) is neither recommended nor useful. Something is broken in the *bigger picture* - take a step back and fix the higher level instead of fighting the entire paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Application.OnTime to accomplish this task.

Book2.xlsm

```
Public wb As Workbook

Public Sub bar(book As Workbook)
'set the variable for the workbook we want to close - We do this because we cannot pass a workbook object
Set wb = book
'set it to call 1 second from now
Application.OnTime DateTime.DateAdd("s", 1, DateTime.Now), "CloseIt"
End Sub


Sub CloseIt()
    wb.Close False
    Debug.Print "Closed Workbook!"
    MsgBox "Closed workbook!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Even if you use an add-in you may face this problem. I found using the below function very useful in handling such problems. Your call stack root won't be in Book1:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "'Book2.xlsm'!Module1.bar", oldBook
```